# div tag of an image with exceeding height

Tags: html, css

I want to design a website that has a logo as shown below.

There is a div tag that contains the header, but as you can see the logo height exceeds that of the header. The dashed lines I have mentioned show the main part of the site. However, the header color spans and covers the width of the screen.

I have used "position:relative" for the logo, but then the navigation in the header would not locate properly.

I would be very grateful if you kindly help me solve this problem.

here are the codes:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header-container">
    <header>
        <nav>nav</nav>
    </header>
    <div id="header-logo"> logo in header </div>
</div>


    <div class="divider"></div>
    <aside id="left">leftside</aside>
    <aside id="right">rightside</aside>
    <footer>footer</footer>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/mainpage-background.jpg);
}

#header-container {
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    height: 115px;
}

header {
    width: 756px;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#header-logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 188px;
    border: thin solid #E93538;
    background-color: #C92C2F;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: A fiddle would be great...

Comment: I Guess you could alternatively create a new div, containing both your header and your logo? Hard to help without any code posted up.

Comment: What is the behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have the logo inside the header though its height exceeds the height of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're explicitly stating the height and width of the image you need to make sure whatever that image is going in, matches the height.

Change your header-container height to match or your logo to match:

```
#header-container {
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    height: 115px;
}

#header-logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 115px; /* To match the container */
    border: thin solid #E93538;
    background-color: #C92C2F;
    float: left;
}

#header-logo img{
   width: 100%; /*since you have only added dimensions to your container not the image itself, just to be sure.*/
}
```

**Edit**
Assuming you're having an image that is.

Comment: the height of the header is 115px but the height of the logo image is 188, I don't want their heights to match. Just if you take a look at this website, you will know what I want: http://www.mcgill.ca/

Comment: What website? You have given no website or a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ If you don't want them to match then one is going to exceed the other. That's like putting a bigger box inside a smaller box and expecting it to fit. Please fill out a JSFiddle and we can help you more.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jam0krx1/2/

Start from there. I've added a wrapper and adjusted your nav width (OriginalNavWidth - LogoWidth)

I've added *{box-sizing: border-box;} this takes into consideration your borders and padding so that everything fits nicely, more info: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: @ Jezzabeanz  sorry me, the website is: www.mcgill.ca

Comment: Please see my newly added answer, it's similar to the website you linked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a navigation wrapper:

## Without Overlap

I redesigned your CSS since I find it easier starting from scratch:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    height: 80px;
}

.logo{
    background: red;
    width: 185px;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;

}
.header-wrap{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 15%;
    height:100%;
}

nav{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width:80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <header>

    <div class="header-wrap">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <nav>
        nav
    </nav>
 </div>
 </header>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Some test header</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to see it in action before you implement it, please see this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ywq1a3uj/

## With Overlap like the website

If you wanted it so that the logo overlaps the content slightly, you need to use position absolute then add a margin to the content which is the hight of the header, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/p1n6aouz/

```
header{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.featured{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 80px;
}


<div class="featured">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-1920-480-9.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp. If your navigation is on a top layer it could seeming glide over the welcome banner.

change these attributes in header-banner the CSS to be proportionally smaller, it should auto-size.

```
width: (WW)px;
height: (HH)px;
```